# pandas apply function on 2.7 and 3.6

Tags: python, pandas

I have one program in python 2.7 trying to update it to python 3.6.

I have found a difficulty on the function `df.apply`

### OLD python 2.7 code:

```
date_cols = ['hour', 'begin_date', 'end_date']
df = df[df[date_cols].apply(_in_daterange, axis=1)]
```

### What I try to do in python 3.6 code:

```
df = df[df[date_cols].apply(_in_daterange, axis=1)]
```

returns an error `variables missing`

#### So instead I have tried this on python 3.6:

```
df = df[df[date_cols].apply(lambda row: _in_daterange(row['hour'],row['begin_date'], row['end_date']), axis=1)]
```

#### But it won't give me the same output.

```
# Function in_date_range
def in_daterange( date: datetime, start, end):
    """ Checks a give date is in the range of two dates """
    if isinstance(start, datetime) and isinstance(end, datetime):
        return date >= start and date < end
    else:
        return False
```

#### What the dataframe looks like:

```
                   hour             begin_date                  end_date
0   2018-01-01 00:00:00                     NaT                     NaT
1   2018-01-01 00:00:00     2018-01-02 11:29:00     2018-01-02 13:00:00
2   2018-01-01 00:00:00                     NaT                     NaT
3   2018-01-01 00:00:00                     NaT                     NaT
4   2018-01-01 00:00:00                     NaT                     NaT
5   2018-01-01 00:00:00                     NaT                     NaT
6   2018-01-01 00:00:00                     NaT                     NaT
7   2018-01-01 00:00:00                     NaT                     NaT
8   2018-01-01 00:00:00     2018-01-02 11:29:00     2018-01-02 13:00:00
```

#### `hour`is generated before to get the range of hours given two dates. Then I perform a merge to get when the events take place

Old program:

- python 2.7
- pandas 0.18

New program:

- python 3.6
- pandas 0.23

Comment: Your function seems to expect 4 inputs but `date_cols` only provides three columns?

Comment: You are right, sorry I copied a different attempt on the function. I have updated the function.

Comment: Why does your 3.6 attempt use `row['hour']` but your function doesn't use hours?

Comment: @jpp `hour`is used to keep a range of hours between two dates. Then I merge the events info using column hour.